# facing issues while integrating the custom pagination component using angular 2

Tags: angular

I have created the custom pagination component using Angular2 but while try to use  it in another component, getting the following error

```
Can't bind to 'offset' since it isn't a known property of 'app-pagination'.
```

### app.module.ts

```
 import { PaginationComponent } from './components/pagination.component';
import { ComplaintModule } from './pages/complaints/complaints.module';
    import { App } from './app.component';
        @NgModule({
          bootstrap: [App],
          declarations: [
            App,
            PaginationComponent
          ],
           imports: [ // import Angular's modules
           BrowserModule,
           ComplaintModule

          ]})
        export class AppModule {
          constructor(public appState: AppState) {
          }
        }
```

Try to integrate in the following html file

### complaints.html

```
<app-pagination [offset]="offset" [limit]="limit" [size]="count" (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)"></app-pagination>
```

### pagination.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagination',
  templateUrl: './pagination.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagination.component.scss']
})
export class PaginationComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() offset: number = 0;
  @Input() limit: number = 1;
  @Input() size: number = 1;
  @Input() range: number = 3;

constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: is complaints component in AppModule ?

Comment: Yes, I have complaints module

Comment: @Und3rTow, having two files..pagination.component.ts and pagination.component.html

Comment: @Und3rTow,  It was working, if i call it in 'complaints.module.ts'. but not working in some other module(reports.module.ts). getting error saying, 'call it in higher module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a seperate `SharedModule` for using `PaginationComponent` in multiple modules

shared.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        PaginationComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        PaginationComponent
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { 
}
```

complaint.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        ...
    ]
    ...
})
export class ComplaintModule {

}
```

some-other.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        ...
    ]
    ...
})
export class SomeOtherModule {

}
```

Now you should be able to use `PaginationComponent` in both `ComplaintModule` and `SomeOtherModule`

Comment: need to call like this, import { SharedModule } from '../../components/shared.module'; in complaints.module.ts?

Comment: it is working fine. I have created the shared component for this...u saved my time. thanks a lot.